# google map api ios crash

Tags: javascript, ios, api, google-maps

One issue facing in iOS with map integration. The application crashes when loading the page with google map multiple times. Will explain the flow of the app below,

App Page1 lists the Districts in a page. When user taps on a district, app will go to next page with the map of the district. In the map, will plot markers (as bubbles) for stores in the district. Users can zoom in/out in the map. Users can tap on the markers so that, it will display the details of the stores.

For creating the map, pure javascript apis are using. Not using any plugins for that. map = new google.maps.Map() is used for creating the MAP. This new map is calling for all page loads.

It seems lots of google map api keeps lots of caches and not clearing the cache. We are using a cache clear plugin. And from the plugin, the following code is used clear the cache.

```
            [self.commandDelegate runInBackground:^{
              // clear cache
              [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
            }];
```

It seems the cache is not clearing and in the instruments the memory is popping up and crashing after few times.

In Android there is no issues, but in iOS the app is crashing.

Any one faced similar issue while implementing map? Any help will much appreciated.

Comment: what does the crash say ?

Comment: use the instruments to debug the out of emory error. See ehre exactly the memory rises up when u r using the app. Use simulator to test this

Comment: each time the map loads the memory getting increased. And I tried to set the map object null and removed the div element for map from the dom. And called removeAllCachedResponses ios function from the plugin. Still the problem exists. In android its working fine.